# Unable to set width less than 84px for Material UI <IconMenu />

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have tried various styling methods but the Dropdown menu does not seem to decrease in width. It is fixed at `84px` no matter how much I try to decrease. It however behaves correctly if I set the width to more than `100px`. I even tried to set `minWidth` on the `menuStyle` which seem to getting applied to the respective `div`.

Should I consider something else or is there a workaround to do this? Any leads would be greatly helpful. I am using `material-ui` version `0.15.4`[image]

```
import IconMenu from 'material-ui/IconMenu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';
import Divider from 'material-ui/Divider';
import Download from 'material-ui/svg-icons/file/file-download';
import ArrowDropRight from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation-arrow-drop-right';
import MoreVertIcon from 'material-ui/svg-icons/navigation/more-vert';

class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <IconMenu
        iconButtonElement={<IconButton><MoreVertIcon /></IconButton>}
        anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'top'}}
        targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'top'}}
        menuStyle={{width: "25px", minWidth: "25px"}}
      >
        <MenuItem key="1" style={{height: "5px", marginBottom: "20px"}} leftIcon={<Download />} />
        <MenuItem key="2" style={{height: "5px", marginBottom: "20px"}} leftIcon={<Download />} />
        <MenuItem key="3" style={{height: "5px", marginBottom: "20px"}} leftIcon={<Download />} />
        <MenuItem key="4" style={{height: "5px", marginBottom: "20px"}} leftIcon={<Download />} />
        <MenuItem key="5" style={{height: "5px", marginBottom: "20px"}} leftIcon={<Download />} />
        <MenuItem key="6" style={{height: "5px", marginBottom: "20px"}} leftIcon={<Download />} />
        <MenuItem key="7" style={{height: "5px", marginBottom: "20px"}} leftIcon={<Download />} />
        <MenuItem key="8" style={{height: "5px", marginBottom: "20px"}} leftIcon={<Download />} />
      </IconMenu>
    )
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this lines to css

```
div[role=presentation] {
  width: 50px !important;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-icon-menu-width)**

Comment: It did not work. Applying class to the `IconMenu` is applying CSS to the collapsed dropdown icon and not the expanded menu.

Comment: @NanduKalidindi, I have tested it and its working 100% fine, I have told to apply class so that svg style wont affect to any other icons.

Comment: Could you please share your snippet. It does not seem to work for me.

Comment: @NanduKalidindi, please check updated answer, provided the Working demo

Comment: But the dropdown menu's width is still at '84px' isn't it. Sorry if I wasn't clear, I don't want the icon size to decrease, I want the whole dropdown menu's width to decrease.

Comment: @NanduKalidindi, Please check now

Comment: The link seems to have broken.

Comment: @NanduKalidindi, cahnge the link please check now.

Comment: Awesome!!! That worked. Thank you very much, I have been dwelling on the old `material ui` all along. The recent one introduced the `role="presentation"` tag.

Comment: Just one more question though, I cannot have multiple widths for different dropdowns right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159443/discussion-between-vivek-doshi-and-nandu-kalidindi).